# Adding values from separate DataRow[] select queries

Tags: c#, .net, database, datarow

I'm trying to pull two values from a db with two separate DataRows and add them together.  For some reason I'm just going blank on what I'm doing wrong, but the variables p1 and p2 are showing as unassigned when I try to add them together.

```
        int p1;
        int p2;
        string count;
        DataRow[] p1Count = dtCount.Select("ATTID = '" + att + " and WAVID = '20111'");
        foreach (DataRow row in p1Count)
        {

            p1 = int.Parse(row["CountValue"].ToString());

        }
        DataRow[] p2Count = dtCount.Select("ATTID = '" + att + " and WAVID = '20112'");
        foreach (DataRow row in p2Count)
        {

            p2 = int.Parse(row["CountValue"].ToString());

        }
        count = (p1 + p2).ToString();
        sb.Append("<td nowrap ALIGN=CENTER colspan='1' bordercolor=#fff><strong>" + count + "</strong></td>");
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is count not what you are expecting? Are you getting a compile error? We have no idea what's not working.

Comment: Sorry, the values p1 and p2 are showing as unassigned when I try to add them together.

Comment: The most likely issue is that your `dtCount.Select()` is not returning any rows. Examine `dtCount`. Does it have rows? It would also help if you showed a little more code and possible the schema of the table you are selecting from. Also what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: They are returning values.  I've trimmed the code down to post here, but there are individual sb.Appends in each of the datarows to add their individual values to the table and they each populate fine.  It is .net 3.5.

Comment: Answered my own question.  Simply had to initialize the variables to 0 as Visual Studio didn't recognize that I was adding values to them before I added them together for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sou you basically changed

```
int p1;
int p2;
```

to

```
int p1 = 0;
int p2 = 0;
```

This solved your problem. This is common mistake.